# Examples of functions satisfying the following constraints -- combining witness reliability and probability

Tags: functions, probability-distributions

I want to find examples of functions of the form $f: [0, 1] \times [0, 1] \rightarrow [0, 1]$ that satisfy the following properties.

(i) If $y' \geq y$ and $y' \geq \frac{1}{2}$ and $x' \geq x$ then $f(x', y') \geq f(x, y)$

(ii) If $\frac{1}{2} \geq y'$ and $y \geq y'$ and $x' \geq x$ then $f(x', y') \leq f(x, y)$

(iii) If $y' > y$ then $f(x, y') > f(x, y)$

(iv) If $x' > x$ and $y > \frac{1}{2}$ then $f(x', y) > f(x, y)$

(v) If $x' > x$ and $y < \frac{1}{2}$ then $f(x', y) < f(x, y)$.

(vi) $f(1, x) = x$ for all $x$

(vii) I'm not sure how best to formalise this, but I also want the functions to be continuous in a natural sense.

A bit of context: *f* is intended to represent a function that combines the reliability of a witness (1st argument) with the probability that the witness assigns to the truth of an event (2nd argument) in order to assign a score representing how much the witness testimony supports/confirms the event. The constraints reflect this interpretation.

For instance, constraint (i) says that, in the event that two witnesses (witness 1 and witness 2) each testify about an event (events A and B, respectively), and witness 1 is at least as reliable as witness 2 and assigns A a favourable probability ($\geq \frac{1}{2}$) that is no less than the probability that witness 2 assigns to B, the overall result of the testimony supports A at least as much as it supports B.

Similarly, constraint (vi) says that if a witness is perfectly reliable, then the degree to which their testimony supports an event is equal to the probability that they assign to that event. Constraint (iii) says that if two equally reliable witnesses testify about an event but the first one assigns it a higher probability, then the testimony of the first witness supports the event more than the testimony of the second.

Comment: @cineel, I don't think they do. In (iii) the first components are equal, while in (iv) the second components are equal.

Comment: @cineel thanks, but I still don't see it. (iii) and (vi) would both be satisfied if f(x, y) was always just y, which shows that they are consistent on their own. Maybe there's an inconsistency when we combine the other constraints with them, but that's not obvious to me.

Comment: Ah I see now, I had the primes the wrong way around, sorry! I fixed it now.

Comment: @cineel, i've now added a bit of context to explain the motivation for the question and the intended interpretation of the constraints. I've tried a bunch of different functions including, e.g. using the arguments as exponents for eachother, multiplying/dividing the arguments etc